# Firebase Authentication in web: No response after user input

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

Trying to implement web app using Firebase Authentication. However, running into an error: after entering email and password information, regardless of if it is correct or not, getting no response, but the page being refreshed.

Here is my login.html:

```
<!-- login.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="login(event)">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
        <br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>


    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.2/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.2/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.2/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
    <script type = "module" src="login.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my login.js code:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, signOut, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, connectAuthEmulator } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
    apiKey: "some-placeholder",
    authDomain: "some-placeholder",
    databaseURL: "some-placeholder",
    projectId: "some-placeholder",
    storageBucket: "some-placeholder",
    messagingSenderId: "some-placeholder",
    appId: "some-placeholder",
    measurementId: "some-placeholder"
});

const auth = getAuth();

var email = document.getElementById("email");
var password = document.getElementById("password");

function login(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var obj = {
        email: email.value,
        password: password.value,
    };
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, obj.email, obj.password)
    .then(function(success) {
        window.location.href = '/chat'
        alert("Logged in successfully")
        console.log(succes)
    }).catch(function(err){
        alert("login error"+err);

    })
    console.log(obj)
}
```

Also, I am getting an error in console, which I think is connected to authentication not working:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rQDH.png)

I am not sure why this error is occurring, because this login.js file is located in the same folder as the entire project and login.html

I tried to change src="login.js" to src="C:\Users\kodil\OneDrive\Documents\Browser\backup\login.js", but it did not help.

To note, not planning to implement sign in option
Users added by owner only should be able to sign in:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfcga.png)